# How to increment the address in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am just starting to lean MIPS assembly, and I am trying to write a simple `while` loop. It will be equivilent to the C code:

`int A[5];`

`for(i=0;i<5;i++) A[i]=i;`

So I know I can use `beq` to make a `while` loop, but I don't know how to increment the memory address each time to go to the next register. I think maybe the `slt` operand may be useful, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming $3 points to A[]

```
lis $4
.word 4
lis $5
.word 1
add $7, $4, $5 ;$7 = 5
add $6, $0, $0 ;$6 = 0

loop:
sw $6, 0($3)
add $3, $4, $3 ;point to next "int"
add $6, $5, $6 ;add 1 to our counter
bne $7, $6, loop ;we will stop at 5
```

Comment: Won't this just overwrite what was in $3 each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Actually I got the sw syntax wrong. So, I flipped the 2 registers. "sw" doesn't overwrite any register, it simply writes to the location pointed to by the register between brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .data

A:  .space  20  #declared 20 bytes of storage to hold array of 5 int

__start:
       lw          $t0, A   #load base address of array
       li          $t1, 0
loop:  sw          $t1($t0), $t1
       addi        $t1, $t1, 4
       ble         $t1, 20, loop
#continue code or simple exit after this
```

Comment: it dose not compile.
loop:  sw          $t1($t0), $t1 -> "(": operand is of incorrect type